# rearrange a sql table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table

```
1      a      10
1      b      11
2      a      4
2      b      8
3      a      5
3      b      4
```

I want to rearrange the table to the following one

```
1    10     11
2    4      8
3    5      4
```

The second column will have the name 'a' and the third the name 'b'.
is this possible?
I'm taking my first step in SQL. Thanks for your support.

Comment: You want to look into [`PIVOT and UNPIVOT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot)

Answer (score 1):

I assume following: table name is `MyTable`, which contains columns: `ID`, `Col2`, `Col3`.

```
select ID,
       max(case when Col2 = 'a' then Col3 end) AS A,
       max(case when Col2 = 'b' then Col3 end) AS B
from MyTable
group by ID
```

Comment: I think it would be better to use **`SUM`** instead of **`MAX`**.

Answer (score 0):

Why use PIVOT/UNPIVOT? Much easier to do it this way:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES (1,'a',10),
                 (1,'b',11),
                 (2,'a',4),
                 (2,'b',8),
                 (3,'a',5),
                 (3,'b',4)) V (Col1, Col2, Col3))
SELECT Col1,
       MAX(CASE Col2 WHEN 'a' THEN Col3 END) AS Col4,
       MAX(CASE Col2 WHEN 'b' THEN Col3 END) AS Col5
FROM CTE
GROUP BY Col1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the simple method:

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(ID INT, NAME VARCHAR(1), VALUE INT)
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES(1,'a',10)
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES(1,'b',11)
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES(2,'a',4)
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES(2,'b',8)
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES(3,'a',5)
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES(3,'b',4)

SELECT ID
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN NAME='a' THEN VALUE END) Value1
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN NAME='b' THEN VALUE END) Value2
FROM @TABLE
GROUP BY ID
```

**OutPut:**

```
ID  Value1  Value2
1     10      11
2     4       8
3     5       4
```